# direct user to different activity when Authenticated with firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have two types of users in my app that connected to Firebase database when I log in I have to direct a user to different screen if USER OR ADMIN after check the ID exists in the database or not check if the user exists it's work fine with me but I didn't know at how can check for ADMIN
**my code for this**

```
     mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(EmailAddress, Password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // Sign in success,
                        Log.i(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                        //getting current user
                        final String user_id  = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    
                        //Read from spesific path
                        mDatabaseReferance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/profile").child(user_id);
                                mDatabaseReferance.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                     
                                      if(dataSnapshot !=null) {
                                          // for(DataSnapshot data :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                          MyUsers user = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyUsers.class);
                                   
                                          hideProgressAnim();
//start user activity

    
                      
                                      }
    
                                          else{     hideProgressAnim();
                                                Log.i(TAG, "START OWNER DASHBORED");
    
                                          }
                                    }
    
    
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to read value.", databaseError.toException());
                                    }
                                });
    
                            }
    
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

here is my firebae structure

```
//my_app
|
|_**user**
|  |__*profile*
|    |__uid1
|     |__uid2
|    |__uid3
|_**admin**
  |__*profile*
     |__uid1
     |__uid2
     |__uid3
```

Comment: why you aren't put a property admin with a boolean value in your User node?

Comment: @AmrJyniat I don't get it can u explain it more please

Comment: OK, instead of creating a new node to store the users who are admin, just put a property for the user (when you add it) in same user node and make this property boolean if the user is admin make it true otherwise make it false.